# Troubles when updating RedBean PHP ORM to the last version using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, redbean

I'm new to RedBean, my application was working, but when I updated RedBean to the last version using Composer, I got this error, 
Fatal error: Class 'RedBean_Facade' not found in my bootstrap.php file :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.inc.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use RedBean_Facade as R;

if (empty(R::$currentDB)) {
    $dsn = sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s', DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME);
    R::setup($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
}

R::close();
```

I don't understand if it's releated to the new version of RedBean or to my Composer autoloader which take into account just one library?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'R' not found
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RedBean_Facade' not found
```

can both be solved using this new syntax:

```
use RedBeanPHP\R;
```

I've tested it successfully in version 4.3.0

Comment: This did not work for me until I used: `use RedBeanPHP\Facade as R;`

Answer (score 0):

I have put the single file `rb.php` into a composer package:

https://github.com/diversen/redbean-composer

As statet in the docs it is recommended to just include the compiled version of redbeans as a single file.